# date in database -1 day as on frond-end

Tags: database, datetime, custom-field

We just found out that in the database birthday field, all dates has 1-day difference than what is shown on the front-end.

On the front-end, it is the correct date by the way.

Question: Is it a bug and if not, why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database will be storing the date as seconds since 1970 (epoch) and your view on that is not localised. However, the front end date is localised for your time zone.

Of this I am more sure than that the sun will rise tomorrow (thanks to a recent rise in right wing politicians).

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion, Jeremy.  I will dive into this to see if you are right.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct. I recommend updating it to add more confidence. ;)

Comment: Hah - lol, done!

Comment: Yes, it works perfect Jeremy :) I was out celebrating this solution, that's why I could not telling you before ;)